How to change text style on Android's Jetpack Compose DatePicker heading and month picker?
how can we change text styles on DatePicker component for heading and monthly picker that are inside the component?

I need to use a RangeDatePicker and the problem doesn't exist in that component, and I know we can change the heading to a Text of my own, but I don't want to implement the logic again and the Month picker is not the same way.

Please edit your post and include some minimal sample code so that we can try to find a solution more easily.
